# wordpress is_front_page() true on woocomerce confirmation e-mail

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to identify a flag for WooCommerce confirmation order template in order to display / hide some information.

For some reason:

```
if(is_front_page()) {
//SHOW ONLY ON HOME PAGE - OK
//BUG: THIS GETS DISPLAYED TO WOOCOMMERCE CONFIRMATION E-MAIL. SHOULDN'T BE HIDDEN ON WOOCOMMERCE EMAILS? 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up using: `class_exists( 'WC_Email' )` and works.